# How to make a table smaller to fit one page (not ugly) or shift a part of the long table to the next page in LATEX

Tags: longtable

I have a long table but I tried first to make it smaller but clear to fit into one page or to shift a part of it to the next page.
To make it smaller I tried this

```
{\tiny\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.1}
\resizebox{!}{.42\paperheight}{%
```

but it is ugly.

here is my table

```
\begin{table}[!htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{bb}
  {\tiny\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.1}
\resizebox{!}{.42\paperheight}{%
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
\cmidrule{1-10}    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .949,  .949,  .949} \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Scenarios}} & \multicolumn{4}{||c||}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}\textbf{Parameters}} & \multicolumn{5}{c||}{\textbf{Performance indicators}} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} \\
\cmidrule{1-10}    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Name} & Vehicle     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{NBW} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Demand} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{NBC} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{LR} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{NBV} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Km/Ton} &  \\
\cmidrule{1-10}    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .851,  .851,  .851} \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{S1} & T     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{(100-500)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{100} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{46,78} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{6,39} & 10,86 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} \\
\cmidrule{1-10}    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .851,  .851,  .851} \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{S2} & T     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{(100-500)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{200} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{47,78} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{12,21} & 10,78 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} \\
\cmidrule{1-10}    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .851,  .851,  .851} \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{S3} & T     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{(100-500)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{300} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{48,78} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{18,18} & 10,47 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} \\
\cmidrule{1-10}    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .851,  .851,  .851} \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{S4} & T     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{(100-500)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{400} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{49,78} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{24,14} & 10,16 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} \\
\cmidrule{1-10}    \multicolumn{1}{c}{S5} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{T} & 1     & (200-600) & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{100} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{50,78} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{6,82} & 8,65  &  \\
\cmidrule{6-10}    \multicolumn{1}{c}{S6} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{T} & 1     & (200-600) & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{200} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{51,78} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{12,64} & 8,11  &  \\
\cmidrule{6-10}    \multicolumn{1}{c}{S7} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{T} & 1     & (200-600) & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{300} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{52,78} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{18,46} & 7,79  &  \\
\cmidrule{6-10}    \multicolumn{1}{c}{S8} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{T} & 1     & (200-600) & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{400} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{53,78} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{24,43} & 7,74  &  \\
\cmidrule{1-10}    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .851,  .851,  .851} \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{S9} & T     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{(100-500)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{100} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{54,78} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{7,10} & 13,45 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} \\
\cmidrule{1-10}    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .851,  .851,  .851} \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{S10} & T     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{(100-500)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{200} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{55,78} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{13,49} & 12,66 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} \\
\cmidrule{1-10}    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .851,  .851,  .851} \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{S11} & T     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{(100-500)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{300} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{56,78} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{19,46} & 11,78 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} \\
\cmidrule{1-10}    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .851,  .851,  .851} \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{S12} & T     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{(100-500)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{400} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{57,78} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{25,56} & 13,98 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} \\
\cmidrule{1-10}    \multicolumn{1}{c}{S13} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{T} & 2     & (200-600) & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{100} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{58,78} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{7,67} & 10,48 &  \\
\cmidrule{6-10}    \multicolumn{1}{c}{S14} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{T} & 2     & (200-600) & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{200} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{59,78} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{13,49} & 9,45  &  \\
\cmidrule{6-10}    \multicolumn{1}{c}{S15} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{T} & 2     & (200-600) & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{300} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{60,78} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{19,88} & 8,96  &  \\
\cmidrule{6-10}    \multicolumn{1}{c}{S16} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{T} & 2     & (200-600) & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{400} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{61,78} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{26,27} & 10,82 &  \\
\cmidrule{1-10}    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .851,  .851,  .851} \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{S17} & V     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{(100-500)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{100} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{62,78} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{21,02} & 30,27 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} \\
\cmidrule{1-10}    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .851,  .851,  .851} \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{S18} & V     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{(100-500)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{200} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{63,78} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{40,76} & 30,67 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} \\
\cmidrule{1-10}    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .851,  .851,  .851} \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{S19} & V     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{(100-500)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{300} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{64,78} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{61,63} & 30,65 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} \\
\cmidrule{1-10}    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .851,  .851,  .851} \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{S20} & V     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{(100-500)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{400} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{65,78} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{82,93} & 30,90 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} \\
\cmidrule{1-10}    \multicolumn{1}{c}{S21} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{V} & 1     & (200-600) & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{100} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{66,78} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{29,68} & 30,18 &  \\
\cmidrule{6-10}    \multicolumn{1}{c}{S22} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{V} & 1     & (200-600) & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{200} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{67,78} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{57,37} & 30,17 &  \\
\cmidrule{6-10}    \multicolumn{1}{c}{S23} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{V} & 1     & (200-600) & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{300} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{68,78} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{85,92} & 29,83 &  \\
\cmidrule{6-10}    \multicolumn{1}{c}{S24} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{V} & 1     & (200-600) & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{400} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{69,78} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{114,46} & 30,11 &  \\
\cmidrule{1-10}    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .851,  .851,  .851} \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{S25} & V     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(100-500)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{100} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{70,78} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{21,59} & 33,67 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} \\
\cmidrule{1-10}    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .851,  .851,  .851} \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{S26} & V     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{(100-500)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{200} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{71,78} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{41,18} & 33,47 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} \\
\cmidrule{1-10}    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .851,  .851,  .851} \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{S27} & V     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{(100-500)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{300} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{72,78} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{61,92} & 32,29 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} \\
\cmidrule{1-10}    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .851,  .851,  .851} \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{S28} & V     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(100-500)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{400} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{73,78} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{83,50} & 32,65 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} \\
\cmidrule{1-10}    \multicolumn{1}{c}{S29} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{V} & 2     & (200-600) & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{100} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{74,78} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{29,96} & 33,01 &  \\
\cmidrule{6-10}    \multicolumn{1}{c}{S30} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{V} & 2     & (200-600) & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{200} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{75,78} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{57,80} & 33,24 &  \\
\cmidrule{6-10}    \multicolumn{1}{c}{S31} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{V} & 2     & (200-600) & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{300} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{76,78} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{86,49} & 32,24 &  \\
\cmidrule{6-10}    \multicolumn{1}{c}{S32} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{V} & 2     & (200-600) & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{400} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{77,78} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{114,32} & 32,09 &  \\
\cmidrule{6-10}    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &       &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .149,  .149,  .149}\textcolor[rgb]{ .851,  .851,  .851}{\textbf{T}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .149,  .149,  .149}\textcolor[rgb]{ .851,  .851,  .851}{\textbf{V}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .149,  .149,  .149}\textcolor[rgb]{ .851,  .851,  .851}{\textbf{T}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .149,  .149,  .149}\textcolor[rgb]{ .851,  .851,  .851}{\textbf{V}}} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .851,  .851,  .851} &  \\
\cmidrule{1-10}    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .851,  .851,  .851} \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{S33} & T+V   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{(100-500)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{100} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{51,38} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{89,75} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{5,96} & 0,14  & 10,67 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} \\
\cmidrule{1-10}    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .851,  .851,  .851} \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{S34} & T+V   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{(100-500)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{200} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{49,95} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{90,96} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{11,64} & 0,57  & 10,73 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} \\
\cmidrule{1-10}    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .851,  .851,  .851} \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{S35} & T+V   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{(100-500)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{300} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{49,73} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{89,75} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{17,75} & 0,28  & 10,22 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} \\
\cmidrule{1-10}    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .851,  .851,  .851} \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{S36} & T+V   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{(100-500)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{400} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{49,65} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{97,08} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{24,00} & 0,28  & 10,22 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} \\
\cmidrule{1-10}    S37   & T+V   & 1     & (200-600) & 100   & 63,72 & 79,73 & 6,39  & 0,43  & 8,57  &  \\
\cmidrule{2-2}\cmidrule{10-10}    S38   & T+V   & 1     & (200-600) & 200   & 65    & 64,17 & 12,50 & 0,14  & 8,10  &  \\
\cmidrule{2-2}\cmidrule{10-10}    S39   & T+V   & 1     & (200-600) & 300   & 65,58 & 82,25 & 18,46 & 0,14  & 7,84  &  \\
\cmidrule{2-2}\cmidrule{10-10}    S40   & T+V   & 1     & (200-600) & 400   & 65,83 & 76,00 & 24,28 & 0,14  & 7,63  &  \\
\cmidrule{1-10}    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .851,  .851,  .851} \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{S41} & T+V   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{(100-500)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{100} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{46,28} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{80,24} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{6,39} & 0,85  & 13,80 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} \\
\cmidrule{1-10}    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .851,  .851,  .851} \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{S42} & T+V   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{(100-500)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{200} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{47,27} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{72,28} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{12,36} & 0,71  & 12,55 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} \\
\cmidrule{1-10}    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .851,  .851,  .851} \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{S43} & T+V   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{(100-500)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{300} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{47,21} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{72,30} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{18,60} & 0,99  & 11,99 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} \\
\cmidrule{1-10}    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .851,  .851,  .851} \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{S44} & T+V   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{(100-500)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{400} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{47,78} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{90,45} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{24,99} & 0,99  & 13,91 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} \\
\cmidrule{1-10}    S45   & T+V   & 2     & (200-600) & 100   & 58,41 & 67,42 & 6,96  & 0,57  & 10,39 &  \\
\cmidrule{2-2}\cmidrule{10-10}    S46   & T+V   & 2     & (200-600) & 200   & 61,19 & 79,73 & 13,07 & 0,43  & 9,35  &  \\
\cmidrule{2-2}\cmidrule{10-10}    S47   & T+V   & 2     & (200-600) & 300   & 61,03 & 94,67 & 19,60 & 0,14  & 8,89  &  \\
\cmidrule{2-2}\cmidrule{10-10}    S48   & T+V   & 2     & (200-600) & 400   & 61,75 & 77,31 & 25,99 & 0,28  & 10,75 &  \\
\cmidrule{1-10}    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
  }}
\end{table}%
```

Comment: For long tables which might need more than one page there is the [`longtable`](https://ctan.org/pkg/longtable) package. You might take a look there. Else you can reduce the fontsize to shrink it a bit. Change the separation of columns (e.g. with `\tabcolsep=0.8\tabcolsep` for 80%). Please note, that you shouldn't use vertical lines in tables if you use `booktabs` (or fix that issue, search on this page for that).

Comment: @ skillmon Can you tell me please how to use \tabcolsep ? thank you

Comment: does any one know how to shift a part of the long table to the next page?

Comment: Neither the table environment nor resizebox allows a page break. If you want to split the tabular you should either use longtable **without** table and resizebox, or create two table environments where each contain one part of the tabular.

Comment: You use the `\tabcolsep` as it is noted in my comment. This only decreases the horizontal space. Just put `\tabcolsep=<any width>` into your code. If it should only apply to the table in question put it inside your `\begin{table}...\end{table}` but prior to `\begin{tabular}` if you stick with table or (if you change to `longtable`) like `\bgroup\tabcolsep=<any width>\begin{longtable}...\end{longtable}\egroup`, if it should apply to every table, put it into your preamble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code. However, I didn't understand how vertical rules were allocated, nor what the eleventh (empty) column was here for. I used `siunitx`to have an alignment on the decimal comma in the last five (non-empty) columns. Also, note that when colouring rows or columns, or using vertical rules while using `booktabs`, you have to set the padding of horizontal rules to `0` if you don't want to get unsightly white strips in the table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry} %
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption, booktabs, cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{3.5pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{3pt}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt} \setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
\sisetup{table-format=2.2, table-alignment=center, copy-decimal-marker}%
\begin{longtable}{|*{5}{Cc|}*{5}{S|} >{\cellcolor{white}}Cc|}
  \caption{bb} \label{tab:addlabel} \\%
  \cmidrule{1-10} %
  \rowcolor{Gainsboro!40} \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\textbf{Scenarios}} & \multicolumn{4}{||c||}{\cellcolor{white}\textbf{Parameters}} & \multicolumn{5}{c||}{\textbf{Performance indicators}} & \\
  \cmidrule{1-10} \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Name} & Vehicle & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{NBW} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Demand} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{NBC} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{LR} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{NBV} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Km/Ton} & \\
  \cmidrule{1-10}
  \endfirsthead
  \multicolumn{10}{c}{\tablename~\thetable: bb\enspace (continued)} \\[2ex]
  \cmidrule{1-10} \rowcolor{Gainsboro!40} \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\textbf{Scenarios}} & \multicolumn{4}{||c||}{\cellcolor{white}\textbf{Parameters}} & \multicolumn{5}{c||}{\textbf{Performance indicators}} & \\
  \cmidrule{1-10} \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Name} & Vehicle & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{NBW} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Demand} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{NBC} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{LR} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{NBV} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Km/Ton} & \\
  \cmidrule{1-10}
  \endhead
  \rowcolor{Gainsboro}
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{S1} & T & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{(100-500)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{100} & \multicolumn{2}{S|}{46,78} & \multicolumn{2}{S|}{6,39} & 10,86 & \\
  \cmidrule{1-10}
  \rowcolor{Gainsboro}
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{S2} & T & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{(100-500)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{200} & \multicolumn{2}{S|}{47,78} & \multicolumn{2}{S|}{12,21} & 10,78 & \\
  \cmidrule{1-10}%
  \rowcolor{Gainsboro}
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{S3} & T & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{(100-500)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{300} & \multicolumn{2}{S|}{48,78} & \multicolumn{2}{S|}{18,18} & 10,47 & \\
  \cmidrule{1-10}
  \rowcolor{Gainsboro}
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{S4} & T & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{(100-500)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{400} & \multicolumn{2}{S|}{49,78} & \multicolumn{2}{S|}{24,14} & 10,16 & \\
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \cmidrule{1-10}%
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{S5} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{T} & 1 & (200-600) & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{100} & \multicolumn{2}{S|}{50,78} & \multicolumn{2}{S|}{6,82} & 8,65 & \\
  \cmidrule{6-10}
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{S6} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{T} & 1 & (200-600) & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{200} & \multicolumn{2}{S|}{51,78} & \multicolumn{2}{S|}{12,64} & 8,11 & \\
  \cmidrule{6-10}%
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{S7} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{T} & 1 & (200-600) & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{300} & \multicolumn{2}{S|}{52,78} & \multicolumn{2}{S|}{18,46} & 7,79 & \\
  \cmidrule{6-10}%
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{S8} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{T} & 1 & (200-600) & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{400} & \multicolumn{2}{S|}{53,78} & \multicolumn{2}{S|}{24,43} & 7,74 & \\
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \cmidrule{1-10}%
  \rowcolor{Gainsboro}%
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{S9} & T & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{(100-500)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{100} & \multicolumn{2}{S|}{54,78} & \multicolumn{2}{S|}{7,10} & 13,45 & \\
  \cmidrule{1-10}%
  \rowcolor{Gainsboro}%
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{S10} & T & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{(100-500)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{200} & \multicolumn{2}{S|}{55,78} & \multicolumn{2}{S|}{13,49} & 12,66 & \\
  \cmidrule{1-10}%
  \rowcolor{Gainsboro}%
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{S11} & T & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{(100-500)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{300} & \multicolumn{2}{S|}{56,78} & \multicolumn{2}{S|}{19,46} & 11,78 & \\
  \cmidrule{1-10}%
  \rowcolor{Gainsboro}%
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{S12} & T & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{(100-500)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{400} & \multicolumn{2}{S|}{57,78} & \multicolumn{2}{S|}{25,56} & 13,98 & \\
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \cmidrule{1-10}%
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{S13} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{T} & 2 & (200-600) & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{100} & \multicolumn{2}{S|}{58,78} & \multicolumn{2}{S|}{7,67} & 10,48 & \\
  \cmidrule{6-10}%
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{S14} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{T} & 2 & (200-600) & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{200} & \multicolumn{2}{S|}{59,78} & \multicolumn{2}{S|}{13,49} & 9,45 & \\
  \cmidrule{6-10}%
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{S15} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{T} & 2 & (200-600) & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{300} & \multicolumn{2}{S|}{60,78} & \multicolumn{2}{S|}{19,88} & 8,96 & \\
  \cmidrule{6-10}%
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{S16} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{T} & 2 & (200-600) & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{400} & \multicolumn{2}{S|}{61,78} & \multicolumn{2}{S|}{26,27} & 10,82 & \\
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \cmidrule{1-10}%
  \rowcolor{Gainsboro}%
  \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{S17} & V & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{(100-500)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{100} & \multicolumn{2}{S|}{62,78} & \multicolumn{2}{S|}{21,02} & 30,27 & \\
  \cmidrule{1-10}%
  \rowcolor{Gainsboro}%
  \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{S18} & V & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{(100-500)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{200} & \multicolumn{2}{S|}{63,78} & \multicolumn{2}{S|}{40,76} & 30,67 & \\
  \cmidrule{1-10}%
  \rowcolor{Gainsboro}%
  \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{S19} & V & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{(100-500)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{300} & \multicolumn{2}{S|}{64,78} & \multicolumn{2}{S|}{61,63} & 30,65 & \\
  \cmidrule{1-10}%
  \rowcolor{Gainsboro}%
  \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{S20} & V & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{(100-500)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{400} & \multicolumn{2}{S|}{65,78} & \multicolumn{2}{S|}{82,93} & 30,90 & \\
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \cmidrule{1-10}%
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{S21} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{V} & 1 & (200-600) & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{100} & \multicolumn{2}{S|}{66,78} & \multicolumn{2}{S|}{29,68} & 30,18 & \\
  \cmidrule{6-10}%
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{S22} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{V} & 1 & (200-600) & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{200} & \multicolumn{2}{S|}{67,78} & \multicolumn{2}{S|}{57,37} & 30,17 & \\
  \cmidrule{6-10}%
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{S23} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{V} & 1 & (200-600) & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{300} & \multicolumn{2}{S|}{68,78} & \multicolumn{2}{S|}{85,92} & 29,83 & \\
  \cmidrule{6-10}%
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{S24} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{V} & 1 & (200-600) & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{400} & \multicolumn{2}{S|}{69,78} & \multicolumn{2}{S|}{114,46} & 30,11 & \\
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \cmidrule{1-10}%
  \rowcolor{Gainsboro}%
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{S25} & V & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(100-500)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{100} & \multicolumn{2}{S|}{70,78} & \multicolumn{2}{S|}{21,59} & 33,67 & \\
  \cmidrule{1-10}%
  \rowcolor{Gainsboro}%
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{S26} & V & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{(100-500)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{200} & \multicolumn{2}{S|}{71,78} & \multicolumn{2}{S|}{41,18} & 33,47 & \\
  \cmidrule{1-10}%
  \rowcolor{Gainsboro}%
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{S27} & V & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{(100-500)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{300} & \multicolumn{2}{S|}{72,78} & \multicolumn{2}{S|}{61,92} & 32,29 & \\
  \cmidrule{1-10}%
  \rowcolor{Gainsboro} %
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{S28} & V & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(100-500)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{400} & \multicolumn{2}{S|}{73,78} & \multicolumn{2}{S|}{83,50} & 32,65 & \\
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \cmidrule{1-10}%
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{S29} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{V} & 2 & (200-600) & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{100} & \multicolumn{2}{S|}{74,78} & \multicolumn{2}{S|}{29,96} & 33,01 & \\
  \cmidrule{6-10}
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{S30} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{V} & 2 & (200-600) & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{200} & \multicolumn{2}{S|}{75,78} & \multicolumn{2}{S|}{57,80} & 33,24 & \\
  \cmidrule{6-10}%
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{S31} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{V} & 2 & (200-600) & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{300} & \multicolumn{2}{S|}{76,78} & \multicolumn{2}{S|}{86,49} & 32,24 & \\
  \cmidrule{6-10} %
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{S32} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{V} & 2 & (200-600) & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{400} & \multicolumn{2}{S|}{77,78} & \multicolumn{2}{S|}{114,32} & 32,09 & \\
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \cmidrule{6-10}%
  \multicolumn{3}{c|}{} & & & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor{DarkSlateGray}\textcolor{Gainsboro}{\textbf{T}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor{DarkSlateGray}\textcolor{Gainsboro}{\textbf{V}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor{DarkSlateGray}\textcolor{Gainsboro}{\textbf{T}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor{DarkSlateGray}\textcolor{Gainsboro}{\textbf{V}}}
                                                                                  & \cellcolor{Gainsboro} & \\*
  \cmidrule{1-10}\rowcolor{Gainsboro} \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{S33} & T+V & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{(100-500)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{100} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{51,38} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{89,75} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{5,96} & 0,14 & 10,67 & \\
  \cmidrule{1-10}\rowcolor{Gainsboro} \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{S34} & T+V & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{(100-500)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{200} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{49,95} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{90,96} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{11,64} & 0,57 & 10,73 & \\
  \cmidrule{1-10}
  \rowcolor{Gainsboro} %
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{S35} & T+V & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{(100-500)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{300} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{49,73} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{89,75} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{17,75} & 0,28 & 10,22 & \\
  \cmidrule{1-10}%
  \rowcolor{Gainsboro}%
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{S36} & T+V & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{(100-500)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{400} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{49,65} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{97,08} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{24,00} & 0,28 & 10,22 & \\
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \cmidrule{1-10}%
  S37 & T+V & 1 & (200-600) & 100 & 63,72 & 79,73 & 6,39 & 0,43 & 8,57 & \\
  \cmidrule{2-2}\cmidrule{10-10}%
  S38 & T+V & 1 & (200-600) & 200 & 65 & 64,17 & 12,50 & 0,14 & 8,10 & \\
  \cmidrule{2-2}\cmidrule{10-10} %
  S39 & T+V & 1 & (200-600) & 300 & 65,58 & 82,25 & 18,46 & 0,14 & 7,84 & \\
  \cmidrule{2-2}\cmidrule{10-10}%
  S40 & T+V & 1 & (200-600) & 400 & 65,83 & 76,00 & 24,28 & 0,14 & 7,63 & \\
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \cmidrule{1-10}%
  \rowcolor{Gainsboro} %
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{S41} & T+V & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{(100-500)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{100} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{46,28} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{80,24} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{6,39} & 0,85 & 13,80 & \\
  \cmidrule{1-10}%
  \rowcolor{Gainsboro}%
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{S42} & T+V & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{(100-500)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{200} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{47,27} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{72,28} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{12,36} & 0,71 & 12,55 & \\
  \cmidrule{1-10}%
  \rowcolor{Gainsboro}%
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{S43} & T+V & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{(100-500)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{300} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{47,21} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{72,30} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{18,60} & 0,99 & 11,99 & \\
  \cmidrule{1-10}%
  \rowcolor{Gainsboro} %
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{S44} & T+V & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{(100-500)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{400} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{47,78} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{90,45} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{24,99} & 0,99 & 13,91 & \\
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \cmidrule{1-10}%
  S45 & T+V & 2 & (200-600) & 100 & 58,41 & 67,42 & 6,96 & 0,57 & 10,39 & \\
  \cmidrule{2-2}\cmidrule{10-10}%
  S46 & T+V & 2 & (200-600) & 200 & 61,19 & 79,73 & 13,07 & 0,43 & 9,35 & \\
  \cmidrule{2-2}\cmidrule{10-10}%
  S47 & T+V & 2 & (200-600) & 300 & 61,03 & 94,67 & 19,60 & 0,14 & 8,89 & \\
  \cmidrule{2-2}\cmidrule{10-10}
  S48 & T+V & 2 & (200-600) & 400 & 61,75 & 77,31 & 25,99 & 0,28 & 10,75 & \\
  \cmidrule{1-10}%
\end{longtable}%

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @bernard, I did solved my problem yesterday alone. thanks a lot